# How to add the same Pizza to Order table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have problem with adding the same pizzas to order. In code, when I'm debugging everything is ok but in database I have problem with adding the same pizza and database add only 1 the same pizza.

My order class :

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Sauces = new List<Sauce>();
        Pizzas = new List<Pizza>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Sauce> Sauces { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }

}
```

I have a method :

```
var newOrder = new Order();

            var listsauces = new List<Sauce>();
            listsauces.Add(ctx.Sauces.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault());
            listsauces.Add(ctx.Sauces.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault());

            newOrder.Sauces = listsauces;

            var listPizzas = new List<Pizza>();
            listPizzas.Add(ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault());
            listPizzas.Add(ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault());
            listPizzas.Add(ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault());

            newOrder.Pizzas = listPizzas;

            ctx.Orders.Add(newOrder);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
```

And ofc database shows

[image]

How to add the same pizza to the same order ?

Comment: It's happening because you are using an N x N relationship.
You need to create a new Entity with Order, Pizza and Quantity members.

Comment: Problem is in your design concept

Comment: @TanvirArjel How to correct model this database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that.

```
public class OrderPizzaItem 
{
    public Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderSauceItem 
{
    public Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Sauces = new List<OrderSauceItem>();
        Pizzas = new List<OrderPizzaItem>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderSauceItem> Sauces { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderPizzaItem> Pizzas { get; set; }

}



var newOrder = new Order();

var listsauces = new List<OrderSauceItem>();
listsauces.Add(new OrderSauceItem { Sauce = ctx.Sauces.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 2});

newOrder.Sauces = listsauces;

var listPizzas = new List<OrderPizzaItem>();
listPizzas.Add(new OrderPizzaItem { Pizza = ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 2});
listPizzas.Add(new OrderPizzaItem { Pizza = ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 1})

newOrder.Pizzas = listPizzas;

ctx.Orders.Add(newOrder);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

PS. Check this code because I wrote the text without checking the syntax.

Comment: Ok but how to model OnModelCreating Method to add this data because when I want to create migration I recive an error "'OrderSauceItems' is based on type 'OrderSauceItem' that has no keys defined."

Comment: How I told before you need to verify. Just add an ID marked as PK .

Answer (score 0):

@andercruzbr  It is my dbcontext :

```
   public DbSet<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Sauce> Sauces { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Idgredient> Idgredients { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   public DbSet<OrderSauceItem> OrderSauce { get; set; }
   public DbSet<OrderPizzaItem> OrderPizza { get; set; }
   public DbSet<PizzaIdgredientItem> PizzaIdgredient { get; set; }
```

It is ok when i have data in database :

```
var newOrder = new Order();
var listsauces = new List<OrderSauceItem>();
listsauces.Add(new OrderSauceItem {SauceId = ctx.Sauces.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 1 });

newOrder.Sauces = listsauces;

var listPizzas = new List<OrderPizzaItem>();
listPizzas.Add(new OrderPizzaItem {  PizzaId = ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 2 });
                listPizzas.Add(new OrderPizzaItem {PizzaId = ctx.Pizzas.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault(), Quantity = 2 });

newOrder.Pizzas = listPizzas;

ctx.Orders.Add(newOrder);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

My Database shows :

[image]

But how to get all elements in my Order and for example sum prices to one order price.